# Counting frequency of billions of strings

Tags: string, word-frequency, bloom-filter

I have 3 billion strings stored in a postgresql database. I want to make a frequency map so I can discard strings that occur fewer than 100 times or more than 100,000 times. What kind of data structure(s) should I use? I'm thinking some kind of bloom filter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HyperLogLog, which lets you estimate the cardinality of a multiset with a small memory footprint.

Here is an [example](http://eugenedvorkin.com/probabilistic-data-structures-bloom-filter-and-hyperloglog-for-big-data/) that uses a java-hll, a java implementation of HyperLogLog. You an search github for implementations in other languages if java does not work for you.

Alternatively, you can use a [standalone implementation](http://armon.github.io/hlld/).